# Find the volume between the two surfaces.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

> Find the Volume of: $x^2+y^2\le z\le \sqrt{6-x^2-y^2}$

**My Attempt:**

So I need to find $\iint_D(\int^{\sqrt{6-x^2-y^2}}_{x^2+y^2}dz)dxdy$, while $D$ is the area of the intersection between the two sufaces.
**Finding $D$:** 
$x^2+y^2=z \Longrightarrow\sqrt{6-(x^2+y^2)}=\sqrt{6-z} \Longrightarrow z^2=6-z \Longrightarrow z^2 +z-6=0 \Longrightarrow \frac{-1 \pm\sqrt{1-4*1*-6}}{2}=-3,2 \Longrightarrow z=2$.
Substitute $z=2$ to find the intersection curve: 
$1=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}$. 

Moving to elliptical coordinates: 
$x=\sqrt{2}rcos(a)$, $y=\sqrt{2}rsin(a)$, $|J|=2r$

And here I got a little stuck, I usually substitute in the inequalities to get  the possible values of $a, r$, but here I'm not sure what to do, feels like I've missed $z$ since if I substitute $r^2\le z$, and in the same time I don't think an ellipsoidal coordinates fits this problem. 
Any help and feedback is really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: $x^2+y^2 = 2$ is a circle.

Comment: @MathLover Hey, thanks alot for the help as always, I got a question about this question, It's weird that I used it but I don't feel like I understand why did I take the intersection of the two surfaces to be $D$, why is it correct? is it because it's the shadow of the surfaces on $xy$ plane, since it is the "biggest" circle? or it's for another reason?

Comment: yes because it is the biggest circle and it is orthogonal to both surfaces. In other words for any $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt2, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, you get a cylindrical shell along z-axis whose height is bound below by paraboloid and above by the sphere.

Comment: @MathLover I think I'm starting to get it but still not quite well, when we found the intersection curve, everything above it is from the sphere and under it is from the paraboloid, and we have $\iint_D (\int^{z_1(x,y)}_{z_2(x,y)})$, now what is $D$, it's the bounds of the integral in the $xy$ plane , and since the intersection curve is the biggest circle, it will decide our bounds in $xy$ plane, when does the integral "change" from calculating the area of cuts of the sphere, to cuts of the paraboloid? (I just wrote everything I'm thinking of while trying to understand) thanks for the help

Comment: the intersection is not in xy-plane but it is parallel to xy-plane. I will tell you this in a bit of non-mathematical way. Say you have been given a bunch of really thin long sticks which you can break according to length needed and use to put inside this region vertically (along z-axis) such that the whole region is filled. What will be the length of the sticks as you move away from the z-axis? Can you see it reducing and finally at the end where there is intersection of both surfaces, the length of the stick will be really small. Now you can look at your integral in a very similar fashion.

Comment: @MathLover That's a really nice way to explain it, what's left for me to link between the image of sticks filling up the region and what parts of the integral is doing each job, What I can guess or try to say is for $\iint_D(\int^{z_1(x,y)}_{z_2(x,y)}dz)dxdy$, the $dz$ part, we're deciding the side borders (for that reason the sticks get smaller as we move away from $z$ axis, and for $dxdy$ it must involve all the places we must place a stick in, which means we must take the biggest circle otherwise we'll miss some places. do you agree with me linking it like this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126391/discussion-between-math-lover-and-pwaol).